# $u_{xx}+y^2u=\sin2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I want to solve the non homogeneous differential equation $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+y^2u=\sin 2x.$$
I have tried to solve it by method of separable of variables. But unfortunately, not able to find out the solution. Please give me some hints to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method of undetermined characteristics and the methods from ODE's. $u=v + w$ where $v$ solves $v_{xx}+y^2 v=0$ and $w = A(y)\sin(2x) + B(y)\cos(2x)$.

Comment: Sir, I am much familiar with solving PDE, please solve it. Thanking you.

Comment: $$v(x,y) = C_1(y)\sin(xy) + C_2(y)\cos(xy)$$

Comment: $ w(x,y) = \frac{1}{y^2-4}\sin(2x)$

Comment: $u=v+w = C_1(y)\sin(xy) + C_2(y)\cos(xy) + \frac{\sin(2x)}{y^2-4}$